# Showing the annihilation of an electron-positron pair

Tags: particle-physics, photons, protons

How to show that the annihilation of an electron-positron pair under emission of one real photon (mass zero) is forbidden by energy-momentum conservation, the emission of two photons is allowed?

Comment: I know the linked duplicate asks for $\gamma\to e^+ e^-$ instead of $e^+ e^-\to\gamma$, but that doesn't make a difference for the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The electron-positron pair has a center-of-mass reference frame where the momentum is 0.

Obviously, there exists no one-photon system with positive energy which has 0 momentum, as the energy-momentum relation for a photon is $E = p c$.

Comment: Is there a way to get it mathematically?

Comment: @user83866 $p=\frac{E}{c}$ for a single photon cannot equal 0, but $p_{epcm}=0$. That's the math.

Comment: @BillN Is it possible show why this statement is true or it is an experimental fact which is not defined theoretically?

Comment: What don't you understand about something non-zero not being equal to zero?  This IS the theoretical result.